# Pass key value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Is this query  right? Can i pass array key like  this?

`mysqli_query("UPDATE subjects SET has_notes = 1 WHERE sub_id = '$notes_data['sub']'");`

If not please help me with a solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE subjects SET has_notes = 1 WHERE sub_id = '".$notes_data['sub']."'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Im surprised no one told you to prepare that query:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE subjects SET has_notes = 1 WHERE sub_id = ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $notes_data['sub']);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

or the object oriented way:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE subjects SET has_notes = 1 WHERE sub_id = ?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $notes_data['sub']);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

Please read up on [**mysqli::prepare/mysqli_prepare**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0):

A simply solution can be this:

```
mysqli_query('UPDATE subjects SET has_notes = 1 WHERE sub_id = ' . $notes_data['sub']);
```

Note: this solution is correct if `sub_id` is an integer field and `$notes_data['sub']` is an integer too

otherwise:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE subjects SET has_notes = 1 WHERE sub_id = '" . $notes_data['sub'] ."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `{` and `}` to enclose the value you're including:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE subjects SET has_notes = 1 WHERE sub_id = '{$notes_data['sub']}'");
```

I'd encourage you, however, to seriously consider writing using MySQLi's prepared statements rather than building up the query like this - if the `$notes_data['sub']` variable has come from the web then you'll be at serious risk of an SQL injection vulnerability.

Why not do something like this:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'UPDATE subjects SET has_notes = 1 WHERE sub_id = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $notes_data['sub']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```